# How to add new dataset in existing pickle file in python

Tags: python, pickle, naivebayes, jsonpickle

I have this pickle file https://github.com/Nilabhra/ethnicity/blob/master/models/ethnicity_classifier_last_name.pkl which is generated from json file https://github.com/Nilabhra/ethnicity/blob/master/json_counts/last_name_ethnicity.json

My question:
How to remove old dataset and put new dataset in .pkl file.

```
import pickle

ethinicity= {"Kumari": {"Hindu,Brahmin": 1.0},"Choopra": {"Jain,Digambar": 1.0}}
pickle.dump(ethinicity, open("ethnicity_classifier_last_name.pkl", "wb"))
```

however the pickle file generated by above code has a different structure, hence its throwing error when i run this code

Answer (score 1):

remove old pickle file and dump new pickle file with new dataset in it.

Comment: its throwing error because newly created pickle has a different format

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the old dict with the new entries before writing to the pickle file

```
import pickle 
import json

#Loading the old json
old_ethnicity = json.load(open('last_name_ethnicity.json','rb'))
ethinicity= {"Kumari": {"Hindu,Brahmin": 1.0},"Choopra": {"Jain,Digambar": 1.0}}

#Add the changes to old dict
new_ethnicity = dict(old_ethnicity, **ethinicity)
pickle.dump(new_ethnicity, open("ethnicity_classifier_last_name.pkl", "wb"))`
```

Comment: getting error after updating pkl file

**AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'prob_classify'**

Comment: Can you add a piece of code to reproduce the error?

Comment: here is the code
https://github.com/Nilabhra/ethnicity/blob/master/app.py